# Javascript Auto-Refresh Class Elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, jquery

Problem:

Values constantly change on db. Need to auto-reload certain elements values without reloading all page. Very similar to collective bidding pages as attached image.

[image]

A simple page Dashboard type with three columns of grid organized data.

How can I effectively reload (AJAX CALL) certain class types, content?

Since these column values change as time goes from db, they have to auto refresh on time interval.

Code Sample:

```
<div class="autovalue">26</div>
<div class="autovalue">20</div>
<div class="autovalue">96</div>
```

Maybe Jquery has a method.

Comment: You could use jquery's $.ajax methods, then on successful postback change the style of the surrounded div/span to reflect the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an interval function, i did this example using jQuery.

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
   $('.refreshClass').each(function(){
      $(this).load(this.href);
   })
}, 900);
```

In my example `<a href="url-to-get.php" class="refresh"></a>` will request the href attribute every 900ms and update the innerHtml.

For a better performance you can cache your selectors and use id instead of classes. :)

Comment: This could be simplified. You can use `this.href` instead of `$(this).attr('href')`. And no need to do `window.setInterval`, `setInterval` is enough.